# VPN blocking internet connection

Tags: internet, vpn, openvpn

I was running a VPN (Proton) but I do not remember setting up a kill switch. I tried connecting this morning when it randomly wanted the password. I provided it and the pop-up would return.

Password is correct copied and pasted from password manager.

I have now removed Proton and I still cannot connect. Please help.

Comment: If you VPN rejects your password (which has previously worked) you should contact the admins/provider, not the forum. Software does not tend to morph or gain intelligence ...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because This is a back end problem, not a client one

Answer (score 0):

that could be the ipv6 leak protection that it leaves
if you run

```
nmcli device
```

you might find that removing it can solve the issue:

```
sudo nmcli connection delete pvpn-ipv6leak-protection
```

if the kill switch is there then you can remove that too by replacing it with the pvpn-ipv6... above